# How to insert value into specific column in csv file using java

Tags: java, opencsv, csvreader, csvwriter

I want write multiple xml file data into one csv file, For first time writing data from first xml into csv file 8 columns created and for second xml file data writing into from 9th column of same csv file, How can we insert the data into specific column. list contains xml data.

```
String[] rowValue = new String[list.size()];
rowValue = list.toArray(rowValue);
writer.writerNext(rowValue,true);
```